# same prefix http request mis-forward by istio VirtualService

Tags: kubernetes, istio

the log of istio-ingressgateway:

```
[2019-11-11T06:09:02.823Z] "GET /notebook/name/test-root1/ HTTP/2" 404 -... outbound|80||test-root.name.svc.cluster.local - ...-
```

my http request with uri :/notebook/name/test-root1/ was forward to host `test-root.name.svc.cluster.local` , while there are two VirtualService's named "test-root" and "test-root1",respectively. Thus lead to a 404 error for test-root1.

Any ideas about how to fix it? Thanks a  lot,XD.

Comment: Can You please add yamls of your virtual services?

Comment: Since the environment is kubeflow,and i found the way to solve this, but the kubeflow community has just fixed it. The [pr](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/commit/956569bac848c390bfedd70b5ced83385b0e73cf#diff-a21c249b4132cc86e12e783cc3e4f275), thanks anyway!

Comment: Happy to hear that! Could You please add small answer and accept it, so if someone from community would have same problem he could find the answer there?

Answer (score 1):

i figure out how this problem came out yesterday, the Kubeflow notebook-controller use istio proxy and set the match scheme as: `prefix`. But they carelessly set the match uri as `xxx/xxx` which lead to request like `xxx/xxxabc` mis-forward.

And they have fixed this bug few days ago, as the pr mentioned in the comment.